# Mostrar Alerta Sweet Alert en VB.NET

Tags: javascript, vb.net, sweetalert

Estoy trabajando con VB.NET ASP.NET y ando tratando de mostrar una alerta con Sweet Alert.

Desde el Back-End Muestro una muy sencilla y no logró implementar una alerta más completa, con los iconos, mensajes y botones personalizados.

Ya intente creando una función con JS pero al llamarla no me trae la alerta.
Agradeceria cualquier aporte de como puedo mostrarla.

```html
If sResp = "UOK" Or sResp = "COK" Then

                'If sResp = "COK" Then cls_hdv.sClave = cls_hdv.sClaveNew
                AsignarText()

                Dim message As String = "Hoja de vida guardada correctamente."
                Dim script As String = "window.onload = function(){ swal('"
                script &= message
                script &=  "')};"
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "SuccessMessage", script, True)

                sResp = "NUOK"
                sResp = "NCOK"
            End If
```

con el código de arriba muestra la siguiente alerta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito mostrar una como esta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: mmm.. no deberias pasarle un html completo a la alerta? solo le estas pasando el mensaje basico...

Comment: Ya lo he intentato pero al pasarle el mensaje el ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript no me la trae

Comment: tal vez estaba mal el html que pasaste?

Comment: Puede que esa sea la posibilidad,no hay forma de pasarle la alerta con JavaScript?

Comment: seguro que si, y algun experto en js te dira como ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece ser la estructura de la alerta, debe añadirle el parámetro `success` para que muestre el icono como tal, en la [documentación](https://sweetalert.js.org/docs/#icon) está especificado.

El primer parámetro es el titulo de la alerta, el segundo el texto a mostrar y el tercero el icono, para este caso `success`.  *(algo así)*

```
Dim script As String = "window.onload = function(){ swal('Mensaje Informativo','"
script &= message
script &=  "','success')};"
```

Comment: Mil Gracias si funciona correctamente, si deseo pasarle mas valores, como botones cambio de texto lo separo por comas igual?

Comment: @AlexMachado así es, igual hay más opciones que puede personalizar y las puede revisar en la documentación.

Answer (score 0):

En el Backend tengo una función para incrustar un script hacia el Frontend

```
Private Sub Swal(ByVal s As String)
    Dim sf As New Literal With {
        .Text = "<script language='javascript'>Swal.fire(" & s & ")</script>"
    }
    Page.Controls.Add(sf)
End Sub
```

Luego, cuando quiero levantar el Sweet Alert desde cualquier parte del código, llamo a la función Swal de la siguiente manera:

```
Swal("'Oops!...','Debe seleccionar un archivo.','warning'")
```

.. y claro, al llamar a la función puedo incluir mensajes con variables:

```
Swal("'Faltan datos:', '" + fd + "', 'error'")
```